# KingswaySoft JSON Source Component: Paging REST requests in SSIS using HTTP header field

Tags: ssis, kingswaysoft

I'm using the JSON Source Component to consume a REST service which returns page info and total records count on a particular field on the header response:

```
X-JSON: {"total":1952,"results":100,"limit":100,"skip":0}
```

Based on KingswaySoft documentation at [How to Work with RESTful Endpoints in your SSIS ETL Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei14s.png)
I understood I need to use the `GetValueFromPreviousResponseHeaders` function to extract the header variable and `GetValueFromJson` to extract the value from json

[image]

I tried it but I can't make `GetValueFromPreviousResponseHeaders` work.

The function:
`GetValueFromJson("{\"total\":1952,\"results\":100,\"limit\":100,\"skip\":0}","$.total")`
returns me `1952` so it's ok.
If I substitute the JSON `"{\"total\":1952,\"results\":100,\"limit\":100,\"skip\":0}"` with the `GetValueFromPreviousResponseHeader` function, it doesn't work:
`GetValueFromJson(GetValueFromPreviousResponseHeaders("X-JSON"),"$.total")`

Anyone know how it works?

Answer (score 0):

I guys, fixed using (DT_I4) a the beginning:

(DT_I4)GetValueFromJson(GetValueFromPreviousResponseHeaders("X-JSON"),"$.total")